# VBA - Excel crashes when clearing values of vertical range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue when I try to clear a specific range, Excel completely crashes.

First some background, I already have some code running to trigger this macro when a value is being changed in a specific cell which contains a formula (C13). Therefore I have following code in

- Module

```
Option Explicit 

Public TargetValue As Variant
Private Const cTarget As String = "C13"

Sub TargetCalc(ws As Worksheet)
    If ws.Range(cTarget) <> TargetValue Then
        MacroRuns
        TargetValue = ws.Range(cTarget).Value
    End If
End Sub

Sub TargetStart()
    TargetValue = Sheet3.Range(cTarget).Value
End Sub

Sub MacroRuns()

Select Case Range("C13").Value
Dim producten As Variant
    Case "Bosbroek bv"
        producten = Array("aardbei bakje", "rode bes bakje", "banaan stuk", "blauwe bes bakje", "braambes bakje", "kiwi groen stuk", "framboos bakje", "jonagold stuk", "clementine kilo", "ananas stuk")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Factuur").Range("B22:B31").Value = Application.Transpose(producten)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Factuur").Range("B32: B138").Value = ""
    
End Select
```

- Specific sheet with name "Factuur"

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 
    TargetCalc Me
    End Sub
```

- ThisWorkbook

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

 TargetStart 

End Sub
```

**Excel crashes when MacroRuns() is run and I try to clear values by using this code (in Module): `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Factuur").Range("B32: B138").Value = ""`**

When I run this line outside this complete structure it does work.

Hoping that someone could help me out, I'm a bit stuck at the moment.

Comment: Any other event handlers?  Try turning off events while clearing the ranges.

Comment: In the article [Statements or labels invalid between Select Case and first Case](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/statements-or-labels-invalid-between-select-case-and-first-case) the first sentence states `You can place nothing but a comment between the Select Case statement and the first Case clause.` Although these statements are kind of contradictory and this may not have anything to do with your case, it would be worth a shot to put the declaration `Dim producten As Variant` in a 'right' place: in the first `Case` or before `Select`.

Comment: @TimWilliams, that worked for me!
Thanks a lot.
Could you explain to me why this could have solved the issue?

Comment: If you take an action in your event handler which can re-trigger the handler or another handler (which e.g.  then re-triggers itself or the original handler), you can get stuck in an endless loop.  Turning off events prevents that: you just need to be careful that you re-enable events when you're done (typically you'd add an error handler to make sure)